# How do I change the function used when aggregating a raster depending on the cells value?

Tags: r, r-raster

I am trying to aggregate a raster using a specialised function that changes depending on the value of the cells.

Here is a raster with some values set to 1 and some to 2

```
r <- raster(matrix(rep(3, 100),100,100))
r[sampleRandom(r, 50, cells = TRUE)[, 'cell']] <- 1
r[sampleRandom(r, 10, cells = TRUE)[, 'cell']] <- 2
r[r == 3] <- NA
```

I then want to aggregate the raster with the the where the value is halved should the original cells value be 2

```
r_agg <- raster::aggregate(r, fact = factor, fun = function(x,...){
  ifelse(x[x == 1], length(na.omit(x))/2^2, (length(na.omit(x))/2^2)/2)
})
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in setValues(out, v) : 
    values must be numeric, integer, logical or factor
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? and if so how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not aggregate. That is, in aggregate the values of multiple cells are used to compute a single new number for larger cells.

```
fun = function(x,...){
  ifelse(x[x == 1], length(na.omit(x))/2^2, (length(na.omit(x))/2^2)/2)
}  

fun(c(1,1,1,1))
#[1] 1 1 1 1
```

Perhaps you do not want to aggregate? Perhaps you want to use focal?

```
library(raster) 
r <- raster(matrix(rep(3, 100),100,100))
r[sampleRandom(r, 50, cells = TRUE)[, 'cell']] <- 1
r[sampleRandom(r, 10, cells = TRUE)[, 'cell']] <- 2
r[r == 3] <- NA

focal(r, w=matrix(1, 3,3), fun)
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look into focal. Thanks!